# RCP Plug in development- org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "": no actual value was found for the argument ""

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I am writing a RCP plugin development application and am getting the following error.  I am following the model service pattern demonstrated in Vogella's "Eclipse 4 RCP" book.  I have two service plugins that I have created and one of the service plugins is dependent on the other.  I am getting the following error when I try to run the application

org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "IService": no actual value was found for the argument "IServiceImpl()"

This happens to be the Plugin that the other plugin depends on.  I declared the plugin as a required plugin in the dependent plugin's Manifest file as well as in the feature and main application plugin.  I would appreciate any insight as to what may be causing the issue.

Comment: Are `IService` and `IServiceImpl` your classes? The injector wants an `IServiceImpl` object but there is none available.

Comment: IService is the interface that my service implements.  I have created a component that specifies that IServiceImpl is the implementation class of the interface.